# Firebase + Android + Spring para criar microserviços

Tags: android, spring, firebase

A ideia é a seguinte:

Eu tenho uma aplicação em android que irá consumir meus serviços que eu irei criar usando Spring. Entretanto, esses serviços devem ter alguma segurança, onde apenas pessoas autenticadas no meu aplicativo podem consumir tais serviços.

Já na minha aplicação Android eu irei usar o Firebase para controlar as autenticações, usando email e senha. Assim, eu não irei precisar configurar nada de segurança no meu servidor, como por exemplo usar o Spring OAuth2.

Minha dúvida é: Assim que o usuário se autenticar no meu aplicativo e em seguida ele quiser consumir algum serviço que eu disponibilizei usando o Spring no Servidor, como por exemplo um GET LIST de alguma coisa, como eu valido que o usuário está autenticado no meu aplicativo, e assim eu posso dar acesso a ele ao serviço pedido?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode checar se ele está logado, pela [documentação](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth) temos o seguinte método:

```
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
            } else {
                // User is signed out
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }
            // ...
        }
    };
```